# removeObserver for Notification Swift3

Tags: ios, swift

I have a strange issue. I register and unregister my Notification like so:

```
func doRegisterNotificationListener() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name(rawValue: "RateAlertRated"), object: nil, queue: nil, using: rateDidRate)
    }

    func doUnregisterNotificationListener() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "RateAlertRated"), object: nil)
    }

    func rateDidRate(notification: Notification) {
        let rating = notification.userInfo?["score"] as? Int
        let message = notification.userInfo?["message"] as? String
        let response = Response(rating: rating, message: message)
        output.presentRated(response)
    }
```

This view controller is in a UITabBarController. `doRegisterNotificationListener` is called in `viewDidAppear` and `doUnregisterNotificationListener` is called in `viewDidDisappear`. When I switch between tabs the register and unregister methods are being called correctly (I tested using a print statement). However if I fire a notification it will still be received even though `doUnregisterNotificationListener` was called last. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Quick note:

Also tried:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
```

This also doesn't work.

Comment: you can also remove your Viewcontroller as observer try this in deinit method
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)

Comment: @Prince tried that and no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code and once i register observer with this type it is not called when you doUnregister it. please try this.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(rateDidRate(notification:)), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "RateAlertRated"), object: nil)
```

Comment: Excellent. this is working now. Also need to remember to make the selector function `dynamic`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with `addObserver(forName:object:queue:using:)` you should remove it in this way:

Create:

```
let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
self.localeChangeObserver = center.addObserverForName(NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: mainQueue) { (note) in
    print("The user's locale changed to: \(NSLocale.currentLocale().localeIdentifier)")
}
```

Remove:

```
center.removeObserver(self.localeChangeObserver)
```

This approach is taken from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver).